# Ignoring NA values in function

Tags: r, function, na

I am writing my own function to calculate the mean of a column in a data set and then applying it using `apply()` but it only returns the first column's mean. Below is my code:

```
mymean <- function(cleaned_us){
  column_total = sum(cleaned_us)
  column_length = length(cleaned_us)
  return (column_total/column_length)
}

Average_2 <- apply(numeric_clean_usnews,2,mymean,na.rm=T)
```

Comment: `sum` also have `na.rm` argument `sum(cleaned_us, na.rm = TRUE)`  Also, you can use `colMeans(numeric_clean_usnews, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Perfect, that works but i think it might be taking the length of the total amount of elements and doesnt disclude NA. I tried na.rm for length and it doesnt use it. Also i wish i could use colMeans but it asks us to make our own

Comment: I didn't notice the length.  You can use `sum(!is.na(cleaned_us))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to use the `na.rm=TRUE` in the `sum` and using it in `apply` is not going to work as `mymean` doesn't have that argument

```
mymean <- function(cleaned_us){
   column_total = sum(cleaned_us, na.rm = TRUE) #change
   column_length = sum(!is.na(cleaned_us)) #change
  return(column_total/column_length)
 }
```

Note that `colMeans` can be used for getting the `mean` for each column.

Comment: That worked for me but why would we do sum(!is.na(cleaned_us)) for the length? Just curious!

Comment: @J.McCraiton  `!is.na(cleaned_us)` gives a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE for non-NA/NA elements, and `sum` will get the sum of those non-NA i.e. `sum(!is.na(c(NA, 3, 5, NA)))#[1] 2`.  However, the `length` will give 4 here.  I guess that is what you wanted, right or you can do `length(cleaned_us[!is.na(cleaned_us)])`, but it would be slower compared to `sum`

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass an `na.rm` parameter to the function you defined, you need to make it a parameter of the function. The `sum()` function has an `na.rm` param, but `length()` doesn't. So to write the function you are trying to write, you could say:

```
# include `na.rm` as a param of the argument 
mymean <- function(cleaned_us, na.rm){

  # pass it to `sum()` 
  column_total = sum(cleaned_us, na.rm=na.rm)

  # if `na.rm` is set to `TRUE`, then don't count `NA`s 
  if (na.rm==TRUE){
    column_length = length(cleaned_us[!is.na(cleaned_us)])

  # but if it's `FALSE`, just use the full length
  } else {
    column_length = length(cleaned_us)
  }

  return (column_total/column_length)
}
```

Then your call should work:

```
Average_2 <- apply(numeric_clean_usnews, 2, mymean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: I think the if statement is redundant. Perhaps set `na.rm` as false in the function definition.

Comment: the definition is for expository purposes, so indeed it would be more compact in a real-world scenario. not sure i see how there is "redundancy" tho

Answer (score 0):

Use `na.omit()`

```
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(sample(c(1:9, NA), 100, replace=TRUE), 10)

mymean <- function(cleaned_us, na.rm){
    if (na.rm) cleaned_us <- na.omit(cleaned_us)
    column_total = sum(cleaned_us)
    column_length = length(cleaned_us)
    column_total/column_length
}

apply(m, 2, mymean, na.rm=TRUE)

# [1] 5.000 5.444 4.111 5.700 6.500 4.600 5.000 6.222 4.700 6.200
```